# joining two (A,B) tables (key of joining in A:1 row=1 data; key of joining in B: 1 row = several data)

Tags: sql, join, hive

I have 2 tables A and B. How can I join this two tables?

A

```
id  |group
6ZE |A
UZC |A
LQY |B
HO7 |B
V4P |C
KR0 |C
```

B

```
id                 |DATA
6ZE, FET, UZX      |50048
UZC, LQY           |89871
LQY, E03           |31579
HO7, 7KT, LXW, EK8 |17260
V4P, MKP, TPJ      |37344
KR0                |50044
```

Comment: You should fix your data structure so you are not storing a list of ids in a single field in `B`.  you should have one row per id in that table.

Comment: Basic normalization is in order

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions, but none of them work in the Hive 0.13.1. Maybe you have a proposition how to change the data structure in table B. It should be: 1 ID = 1 data?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select *
from Table1 A
join Table2 B on A.id in split(B.id,'\\, ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following...

```
select * from A, B where B.id like concat('%', A.id ,'%');
```

Answer (score 0):

### DDL&DML

```
          CREATE TABLE A_TABLE
          (ID VARCHAR2(50),GROUPP VARCHAR2(50))

          INSERT INTO A_TABLE(ID,GROUPP)VALUES('6ZE','A');
          INSERT INTO A_TABLE(ID,GROUPP)VALUES('UZC','A');
          INSERT INTO A_TABLE(ID,GROUPP)VALUES('LQY','B');
          INSERT INTO A_TABLE(ID,GROUPP)VALUES('HO7','B');
          INSERT INTO A_TABLE(ID,GROUPP)VALUES('V4P','C');
          INSERT INTO A_TABLE(ID,GROUPP)VALUES('KR0','C');
          COMMIT;

          CREATE TABLE B_TABLE
          (ID VARCHAR2(50),DATA VARCHAR2(50));


          INSERT INTO B_TABLE(ID,DATA)VALUES('6ZE, FET, UZX','50048');
          INSERT INTO B_TABLE(ID,DATA)VALUES('UZC, LQY','89871');
          INSERT INTO B_TABLE(ID,DATA)VALUES('LQY, E03','31579');
          INSERT INTO B_TABLE(ID,DATA)VALUES('HO7, 7KT, LXW, EK8','17260');
          INSERT INTO B_TABLE(ID,DATA)VALUES('V4P, MKP, TPJ','37344');
          INSERT INTO B_TABLE(ID,DATA)VALUES('KR0','50044');
          COMMIT;
```

### And select script

```
  SELECT A.ID,A.GROUPP,B.ID,B.DATA
              FROM
              A_TABLE A
              JOIN
              B_TABLE B
              ON B.ID LIKE '%'||A.ID||'%'
```

split is not **common** function

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM A_TABLE INNER JOIN B_TABLE ON FIND_IN_SET(A_TABLE.id, B_TABLE.id)
```